# VB.NET ManagementObject Help

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to create a function to convert a mapped drive path to a UNC path.  I did some googling and found [several](http://groups.google.nu/group/DotNetDevelopment/msg/6caffd33ad1eae11) [different](http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.Asp?ID=397) [pages](http://www.devx.com/vb2themax/Tip/18960) on the matter. I am most interested in the first one, but I cannot seem to get the code to cooperate. Since the original post was in C#, here is my VB.NET conversion:

```
Public Shared Function GetUniversalName(ByVal sFilePath As String) As String
    If sFilePath = String.Empty OrElse sFilePath.IndexOf(":") Then
        Return sFilePath
    End If
    If sFilePath.StartsWith("\") Then
        Return (New Uri(sFilePath)).ToString()
    End If

    Dim searcher As New ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT RemoteName FROM win32_NetworkConnection WHERE LocalName = '" + sFilePath.Substring(0, 2) + "'")
    For Each managementObject As ManagementObject In searcher.[Get]()
        Dim sRemoteName As String = TryCast(managementObject("RemoteName"), String)
        sRemoteName += sFilePath.Substring(2)
        Return (New Uri(sRemoteName)).ToString()
    Next
    Return sFilePath
End Function
```

I have imported `System.Management`, but VS2008 says `ManagementObjectSearcher` and `ManagementObject` are not defined.  Can anyone push me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add System.Management in your references as well.